# What's the theory (principle) behind shapely.ops.polygonize?

Tags: shapely, polygonize, gis-principle

I am learning Python package *Shapely*, but quite confused about the principle behind the `polygonize` function --- [`shapely.ops.polygonize`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.polygonize). How does this function work to polygonize a set of lines (represented by the two endpoints)? What is the algorithm behind that?

Comment: Shapely is a wrapper for [GEOS](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/tree/master/src), which is a port to C++ of the [Java Topology Suite](https://github.com/locationtech/jts). You can inspect the source code of either of those libraries to see the polygonize algorithm code.

Comment: The GEOS and JTS source code is [here](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/tree/master/src/operation/polygonize) and [here](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/tree/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/operation/polygonize) respectively.

Comment: And you may want to leave a backlink to here in your [issue](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/1084) in the shapely repository.

Comment: Thank you @user2856 and @Jeremiah England for the link to the source code! I had a look at the [polygonize](https://github.com/libgeos/geos/tree/master/src/operation/polygonize) operation of GEOS, yet still not very clear. As I understand, it creates edge rings and then build polygon graphs, while how to create `edge rings` remains confused for me.